Distinct characters and distinct sizes
In this challenge you will write a program or function which takes a string and calculates its score.
The score is the number of distinct characters, plus each integer \$n\$ such that there is a character appearing exactly \$n\$ times.
For example the string abcaaccac should score 8, since there are 3 distinct characters, and there are characters appearing once (b) and four times (a and c).
\$
3+1+4=8
\$
For this challenge you should consider "character" and "byte" to be synonymous. Your program should support all bytes in the printable ASCII range, plus any bytes appearing in your program.
The goal is to minimize the score of your source code.
Test cases
"" -> 0
"a" -> 2
"aa" -> 3
"aaa" -> 4
"ab" -> 3
"aab" -> 5
"aaab" -> 6
"abab" -> 4
"abc" -> 4
"abccbcb" -> 7
"abaccac" -> 7
"abcaaccac" -> 8
"emmmmmmmm" -> 11
"abcc" -> 6
"aabcc" -> 6
"aabbcc" -> 5


Why are people positing a 'score' in their header instead of bytes? how do I score my code?

@IntroductionToProbability Feed your code into your program

JavaScript (Node.js), 152 bytes, score = 27
p=>p.split(s=t=[]||(l,lll,i|iiii,mmmmmmhh,aa,u>uu>u>u>u.u.l.litt)).map(a=>-p.split(a,s[[,a]]=s[[,a]]||--t).push()).map(h=>s[h]=s[h]||-(t-=-h-([]>h)))|-t

Try it online!

Uiua, score 11
/+⊂⧻∩◴⟜°⊚⊛

Try it!
/+⊂⧻∩◴⟜°⊚⊛
           ⊛  # classify (convert to numbers)
       ⟜°⊚   # get counts, keeping original
     ∩◴       # deduplicate both
   ⧻          # take the length of the deduplicated string
  ⊂           # join it to the counts
/+            # and sum


Perl 5 -MList::Util=uniq,sum -pF, 37 bytes, score 29
map$;{$_}++,@F;$_=%;+sum uniq values%

Try it online!

-2 score by equalizing count of characters with a comment

Retina 0.8.2, 45 bytes, score 44
$
¶$`
Dr`.\G
O`\G.
\G(.)\1*
$.&$*1¶
D`\G.+¶
.

Try it online! Link includes test cases. Explanation:
$
¶$`

Duplicate the input on a second line.
Dr`.\G

Deduplicate the characters of the copy.
O`\G.

Sort the characters of the original.
\G(.)\1*
$.&$*1¶

Get the counts (in unary) of each character.
D`\G.+¶

Deduplicate those counts.
.

Sum the counts and add on the number of deduplicated characters.

Python, 26 25 score
-1 score thanks to @l4m2
lambda p:sum(set(map(p.count,p)),len(set(p)))#bbbbdddd    ::::....ccccoooo,,,####lllnnnuuuaammeesstt

Attempt This Online!

Python, 100 bytes: score 25

I am new to code golf. what does the comment after your code mean?

@IntroductionToProbability To lowen score

R, score 40 29
-9 thanks to @pajonk
\(m,n=utf8ToInt(m))sum(unique(n)|T,unique(table(n)))######,,,,\\\\\=====|||||88888aaaaabbbbbeeefffffiiiiIIIIIlllllmmmoooooqqqqssssstttTTTT

Attempt This Online!

score 36. Also you can probably lower the score with a comment at the and as other answers do.

APL+WIN, 57 bytes, score 41
Prompts for string.
(⍴v)++/((n⍳n)=⍳⍴n)/n←v-¯1↓0,v←(~v=1↓v,0)/⍳⍴v←v[⍋v←⎕av⍳,⎕]

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

J, 16 bytes (Score = 12)
(#+/@,~.)@(#/.~)

Try it online!

(#/.~) Counts of each unique char
#...,~. Cat the uniq of that ~. with its length # (note: its length represents the number of unique chars)
+/@ And sum


Charcoal, 25 bytes, score 24
Ｆθ⊞υ№θιＩ⁺ＬΦθ⁼κ⌕θιΣΦυ⁼κ⌕υι

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
Ｆθ⊞υ№θι

Get the counts for each input character.
Ｉ⁺ＬΦθ⁼κ⌕θιΣΦυ⁼κ⌕υι

Add the number of deduplicated input characters to the sum of the deduplicated counts.

PowerShell Core, score 34
{sal l group;($a=$args|l).length+(($a|% count|sort|gu)-join"+"|iex);$l="`````"$%%%%(())+++----....;;;===  acccceeeghhhhiiijjjjnnopppprrssttuuxxxx"}

Try it online!

Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 42 31 Score ( 54 108 bytes)
(Length[#]+Total@Union[Values[#]])&@*Counts@Characters@#&(*((LLLeggghh[#]+++TTTollUUUiiiVVVuus))&&*CCrrccc*)

Edit: Tweaked code to score better with a comment string added
Try it online!

Maple, score = 42 (68 bytes)
f:=s->add({(f:=seq(numboccur([seq(s)],a),a in{seq(s)}))})+nops([f]);

numboccur counts characters of type a, where the seq maps a over the unique characters in the string s, to give f (for this program) equal to
2, 7, 7, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 7, 2, 2, 2
f is made into a set of unique character frequencies {1,2,3,7} which is added to give 13, and then we add the number of distinct characters, nops([f])=29, to give 42.

Vyxal, score 9
sĠ₌L@UJ∑

Try it Online!
Explained
sĠ₌L@UJ∑­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
sĠ        # ‎⁡Sort the input and group by consecutive characters
  ₌L@     # ‎⁢To that:
   L      # ‎⁣  Push the length of the whole list
    @     # ‎⁤  And the length of each group
     U    # ‎⁢⁡Uniquify the group lengths
      J   # ‎⁢⁢Prepend the number of unique characters
       ∑  # ‎⁢⁣And sum that


Created with the help of Luminespire.
